# Extracting Text from HTML using HTML::TreeBuilder

Tags: perl, html-parsing

Hi i'm using [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) / [`HTML::Element`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aElement) to clean up some bad HTML produced by programs such as Microsoft Word.

Given the snippet of bad HTML in the example I need to extract the text between `mosh="start"` and `mosh="stop"`. Note this is an arbitrary attribute set elsewhere in the code.

Also note that this is only an example: the only guarantee are the `div` where mosh starts and stops. These could also be tables or `<p><b>`.

The code below achieves this but each line is extracted multiple times because each child also has children.

`$MoshText` should be

```
Good Text can be pattern matched Wanted Text More Wanted TextYet More Wanted Text
```

But after the table

`$MoshText` is

```
Good Text can be pattern matched Good Text can be pattern matched Good Text can be pattern matched Good Text can be pattern matched
```

I then need to split `$MoshText` on `m/matched/` into two strings and remove whatever object the original text was in.

How can I modify the code below to achieve this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use HTML::Element;

my $body =qq(
<body>
  <div mosh="start">Div where mosh set to start</div
  <div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td</td>
    <th>Good Text can be pattern matched</th>
    <td></td><td</td>
  </tr> 
</table
</div>
<p>

   <p>
      <b>Wanted Text</b>
   <br>
      <p><b>More Wanted Text</b></p>
   <div>
      <p><b>Yet More Wanted Text</b></p>
   </div>
  </p>
<div mosh="stop">Div where mosh set to stop bellow here is not needed</div>
);

my ($MoshText, $Flag);

my @kids = $body->content_list();
while (@kids) {
    my $child = shift @kids;
    if (ref $child) {
        my $Mosh = child->attr("mosh");
        if ($Mosh eq "start") {
            $Flag = 1;
        }
        if ($Mosh eq "stop") {
            $Flag = 0;
            last;
        }
        if ($Flag == 1) {
            my $T = $child->as_trimmed_text;
            $MoshText = $MoshText . " " . $T;
        }
        unshift @kids, $child->content_list;
    }
}
print $MoshText . "\n";
```

**EDIT**

To clarify what I meant by  *remove whatever object the original text was in*

the table containing "Good Text can be pattern matched" shouldn't be in a table but a div

I'm amusing  is an object so I'd replace this object with a new div object something like

```
my $new = HTML::Element->new('tag','div');
$new->attr('class', 'MyClass');
$new->push_content('Good Text can be pattern matched');
```

but how would i now find the table delete and insert $new

**Cleaned Output**

```
    <div>
      Div where mosh set to start
    </div> 
    <div class ='MyClass'>
      Good Text can be pattern matched
    </div>
    <div class ='AnotherClass' >
      Wanted Text More Wanted Text Yet More Wanted Text
    </div>
    <div mosh="stop">Div where mosh set to stop bellow here is not needed</div>
```

Hope that makes more sence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you understand why your code isn't working. You are printing the text value of all the elements in the HTML, and because an element's text value includes *all* of its descendants' text nodes several pieces of text are appearing more than once.

You need to process the HTML tree recursively, checking the value of the `mosh` attribute for each element and keeping a flag accordingly (as you already do) and printing text nodes as you come across them only if the flag is set.

This program demonstrates. I have shown splitting the string on `matched`, but I'm not clear what you mean by *remove whatever object the original text was in*.

```pl
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use HTML::Element;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new->parse_file(*DATA);

my $wanted;
my @mosh_text;
my @nodes = ($tree);

while (@nodes) {

  my $node = shift @nodes;

  if (not ref $node) {
    push @mosh_text, $node if $wanted;
  }
  else {

    my $mosh = lc($node->attr('mosh') // '');
    if ( $mosh eq 'start' or $mosh eq 'stop' ) {
      $wanted = $mosh eq 'start';
    }

    unshift @nodes, $node->content_list;
  }
}

my $mosh_text = "@mosh_text";
print "$_\n" for split/\s*matched\s*/, $mosh_text;

__DATA__
<body>
  <div mosh="start">Div where mosh set to start</div
  <div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td</td>
    <th>Good Text can be pattern matched</th>
    <td></td><td</td>
  </tr> 
</table
</div>
<p>

   <p>
      <b>Wanted Text</b>
   <br>
      <p><b>More Wanted Text</b></p>
   <div>
      <p><b>Yet More Wanted Text</b></p>
   </div>
  </p>
<div mosh="stop">Div where mosh set to stop bellow here is not needed</div>
```

**output**

```
Div where mosh set to start Good Text can be pattern
Wanted Text More Wanted Text Yet More Wanted Text
```

Comment: Thank you  for swift response please see my edit regarding what i mean 'by remove whatever object the original text was in' I take an object to mean any HTML element div, P, B etc.

Comment: @Holly: But the text comes from various different elements inside the HTML. Can you show, using your sample code, what the HTML would look like once the appropriate elements were removed?

Comment: Apologies I should of done that in the first place please see my second edit showing the Cleaned Output i'm trying to achieve. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML::TreeBuilder to parse the HTML page, but then use the look_down()/look_up()/right()/left() methods of HTML::Element to find your mosh-attribute boundaries.

Given your boundaries, you can use the look_up/look_down methods (on the bounding elements, rather than the tree root) to find the element that contains the text that you want change.  Change the text in the element and then you can HTML using the as_HTML method from the tree root or any other element.

So in psuedocode:

```
$tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->parse($something)
$mstart = $tree->look_down(
                            _tag => "div",
                            class  => "mosh_start"
                           )
###
# 1. now use HTML::Element traversal methods to find the element that contains the text to match

# 2. use the content manipulation methods to change the content

# 3. rewrite the file
$tree->as_HTML().
```

See also [HTML::Element](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aElement) which along with [HTML::TreeBuilder](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) is a part of the [HTML::Tree](https://metacpan.org/release/HTML-Tree) release on the CPAN.

Answer (score 0):

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
my $t = HTML::TreeBuilder->new->parse_file("China.data");

sub list
 {my ($t, $d) = @_;
  $d //= 0;
  if (ref($t))
   {say "  "x$d, $t->tag;
    for($t->content_list)
    {list($_, $d+1);
    }
  }
 else {say "  "x$d, dump($t)}
}
```

list($t);